# zIndex doesn't work on react-native-maps ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

My user Icon is currently appearing behind the map marker as shown in the picture. It seems to work fine when I use showsUserLocation={true} in android. Is there a way to push the userlocation icon infront of the mapmarker? Have also gone through the options on here but still no luck github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1668

I've tried to use zIndex={-1} but that didn't push the mapmarkers behind the userlocation.

[image: Map Icon appears infront of showUserLocation icon]

```
               <Map
                ref={refMap}
                onPress={onDeselectVenue}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                customMapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
                showsMyLocationButton={false}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: coordinates.latitude,
                    longitude: coordinates.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.05,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.05,
                }}>
                {
                    state.clubLocations.map((clubLocation) => <ClubMarker key={clubLocation.clubId} zIndex={-1} inactive={isInactive(clubLocation)} onPress={onSelectLocation(clubLocation)} coordinate={clubLocation.location} />)
                }
            </Map>
```

ClubMarker component

```
const ClubMarker = styled(Marker) <{ inactive: boolean }>`
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
opacity:${props => props.inactive ? 0.25 : 1.0};
`

type ClubMarkerProps = MarkerProps & {
    coordinate : Coordinate,
    inactive: boolean
}

const ClubMarker = (props : ClubMarkerProps) => 
<ClubMarker onPress={props.onPress} coordinate={props.coordinate} inactive={ props.inactive }>
    <Icons.PinClub width=40 height=40 />
</ClubMarker>
```

Comment: Can you post your <ClubMarker /> component? I checked my map and no matter what zIndex is,  userLocation is in front of the marker.

Comment: yup one second ill update it now

Comment: @OnurEker I've updated the code :)